# Regular expression to extract string text

Tags: regex

- My Input: Fwd: [ProQuest Alert] test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3
- My output needs to be:  test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3
- My wrong output: test TestFwd: test2fwd:

this my Regexp:

```
 ?\b(Fwd:)|\[(.*?)\] ?
```

any help will be gratefully received.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try [`^.*?\[.*?]\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/z72mrg/2) and replace with empty string. Or extract using a capturing group: [`\[.*?]\s*(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/z72mrg/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `replace` with this regex: `/^.*?\[.*?]\s*/`

Explanation:

- `^` asserts position at start of the string

  - `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
  - `\[` matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)

    - `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
    - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
  - `]` matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
  - `\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

```js
var str = "Fwd: [ProQuest Alert] test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3";
str = str.replace(/^.*?\[.*?]\s*/, ' ');
console.log(str)
```

Comment: my input put is like that Fwd: [ProQuest Alert] test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3

Comment: Thanks for your update and if i have this input: fwd: [ProQuest Alert] test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3 fwd:  also every fwd: no concatenated   need to be deleted also

Comment: @anothernode basically I want to delete just  `Fwd:` and every word between square brackets

Comment: That is what the answer does. As far as I can see, it is a perfect answer for your question, it won't get any better ;)