# RegExp to Parse and replace specific Words

Tags: javascript, regex

- My Input: `Fwd: [ProQuest Alert] test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3 Fwd: fwd:`
- My output needs to be:  `test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3`
- My wrong (Parse) output: `test TestFwd: test2fwd: test3`

I want to delete the words `Fwd:` and `[ProQuest Alert]` (the string that's  between square brackets) and not the Fwd: that's Part of the string text

Explanation:

`\[(.*?)\]` ->  to extract text between square brackets (regex globally)

The `\b` denotes a word boundary, which is the (zero-width) spot between a character in the range of "word characters" (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) and any other character

This my Regexp:

```
 ?\b(Fwd:)|\[(.*?)\] ?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qlTpWb/7

```js
    var str = "Fwd: [ProQuest Alert] test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3 Fwd:";
    str = str.replace(/ ?\b(Fwd:)|\[(.*?)\] ?/gi, ' ');
    console.log(str)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to extract string text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408636/regular-expression-to-extract-string-text)

Comment: I would use the `\s` escape character for the space character as it makes it more explicit to see that it is a space at the begining of your regex (and not a space by mistake).

Comment: Why not simply use `^.*]\s?` for your regex? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/514219py/).

Comment: @AminNAIRI I want to delete all the Fwd: that's not concatenated with other string text also all the text string between square Brackets  your example just delete the string that's before the square brackets and the string Brackets

Comment: just remove `i` in your regex flags

Comment: @Fefux no, I need the 'i' for the insensitive case also

Comment: @MokiNex ok, so add this constraint in your question, otherwise, by removing i flag, you get the expected output

Comment: @Fefux done ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this regular expression?

```
var str = "Fwd: [ProQuest Alert] test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3 Fwd:";
str = str.replace(/\b(Fwd:)(\s|$)|\[(.*?)\]/gi, ' ');
console.log(str)
```

I only tried it in regex101.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot! yes that's the perfect answer

Comment: just add the `\s*` in the last of the regexp to  matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to **match** what you don't want and to **capture** what you do want to be removed:

```
keep_me1|keep_me2|(delete_me)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2w4Mpd/1).

---

As lookbehinds and `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` are not supported, you need some programming functionality:

```js
let data = 'Fwd: [ProQuest Alert] test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3 Fwd: fwd:';
let regex = /\w+:\w+|(\[[^\[\]]+\]|\bFwd:)/gi

data = data.replace(regex, function(match, group1) {
    if (typeof(group1) == "undefined") {
        return match;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: your output contains the word fwd: and that's doesn't match the requirement.

Comment: Thanks but still wrong the output needs to be `test fwd:TestFwd: test2fwd: fwd:test3`

Comment: @MokiNex: Last bid :)